# What is the cleanest way to display a java.util.Calendar object in JSF?

Tags: jsf, calendar

We have an object with `java.util.Calendar` objects. We would like to display the data on a JSF page (preferably in the same format we have for `java.util.Date` objects). It seems like there should be some clean way to do this other than creating a wrapper class just to convert the Calendar to a Date.

What is the cleanest way to display the date/time held in a `java.util.Calendar` in a JSF page?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Use [`Calendar`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html)'s own getter [`Calendar#getTime()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#getTime%28%29). It returns a [`Date`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Date.html). Then you can use [`<f:convertDateTime>`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/javaserverfaces/2.0/docs/pdldocs/facelets/f/convertDateTime.html) the usual way.

```
<h:outputText value="#{bean.calendar.time}">
    <f:convertDateTime type="both" dateStyle="long" />
</h:outputText>
```

Comment: doh! Making me wonder how I make it in this profession as usual. Thanks BalusC!

Comment: is there a clean way to do this backwards and take an inputted string and convert it to a `Calendar` object using `<f:convertDateTime>`?

Comment: @BalusC Could it not be something like this? <h:inputHidden id="date" value="#{date.date}"><f:convertDateTime pattern="MM/dd/yyyy"/></h:inputHidden>

Comment: @JakeLong I think BalusC wanted to say, that there is no default way to do it. Always feel free to create your own converter that translates from backing bean to JSF `(getAsString)` and back from JSF to the backing bean `(getAsObject)`. Here a tiny tutorial. http://www.mkyong.com/jsf2/custom-converter-in-jsf-2-0/

Answer (score 3):

For others and @seangates: You CAN apply a pattern if using the Calendar object. E.g.

```
<h:outputText value="#{bean.calendar.time}" styleClass="date">
    <f:convertDateTime pattern="EEEE, MMMM d yyyy" />
</h:outputText>
&nbsp;
<h:outputText value="#{bean.calendar.time}" styleClass="time">
    <f:convertDateTime pattern="hh:mm" />
</h:outputText>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need futher Text:

```
<h:outputFormat
    value="#This my date: {0,date,long}">
    <f:param value="#{bean.calendar.time}" />
</h:outputFormat>
```

see: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/MessageFormat.html